# FireFox. How to create a bootstrap extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox4

It isn't a coding question(I think :)). [I have read manual about how to add bootstrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions) in to my FireFox extension, but what doing next?

I added bootstrap.js, modify install.rdf, what to do next? 
What I need to do wiith my files in content folder?

My extension structure:

```
./chrome.manifest
./Icon.png
./Install.rdf
./chrome/content/Overlay.xul
./chrome/content/Overlay.js
./chrome/content/Options.xul
./chrome/content/Options.js
./chrome/content/Window1.xul
./chrome/content/Window1.js
./chrome/locale/<locales>
```

I written FireFox extension that's need browser restart, but restart isn't needed for extension work. I want remove that action, and I found something about bootstrap.

I think, now I need manually (un)register my windows, overlays, locales, where read about that?

Please, give me more info, url, links, how to modify my extension into bootstrapped.

Comment: I can't believe in a fact, that nobody doesn't knows anything about that :D

Answer (score 0):

Some `chrome.manifest` directives, e.g. `chrome`, `skin`, `locale`, [are supported in bootstrapped extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Chrome_Registration#Instructions_supported_in_bootstrapped_add_ons), so nothing special you need to do there.

Overlays are not supported, however. You need add some code that will use the DOM APIs to manually insert and/or change elements you normally would have in your overlay.
The ["Further reading"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions#Further_reading) section of the docs you already linked contains some stuff. Most bootstrapped add-ons I encountered use some variation of the [`watchWindows` stuff](https://github.com/Mardak/restartless/blob/watchWindows/bootstrap.js).

It might be also helpful to look at real world examples, such as [Restartless Restart](https://github.com/erikvold/restartless-restart-ffext) (which happens to be rather small, and easy enough to understand).